# Windows Subsystem on Linux - Create new cmd-window instance with bash script

Tags: windows, bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using the Windows Subsystem on Linux (Ubuntu) and would like to be able to run multiple processes in parallel from my bash script by creating multiple cmd-window instances of the Ubuntu shell. Is this possible?

I tried using gnome-terminal to run multiple commands via:

```
gnome-terminal -e "command"
```

But it returned the error:

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch= --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
```

And it seemed like people were having trouble using gnome-terminal.

Any ideas for accomplishing this? Thanks.

Comment: The console (conhost.exe -- also used by WSL) is not a CMD window (there's no such thing), but CMD can be used here. Use its `start` command to run another instance of bash.exe that's attached to a new console, e.g. `cmd.exe /c start bash.exe`. Running gnome-terminal obviously won't work without an X11 server. I don't know if that's possible with WSL or if there are plans to make it possible. AFAIK it's just meant for command-line and text UI programs.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 14393 and above:

```
cmd.exe /c start bash.exe -c ls
```

Comment: Thank you for answering a question. You maybe want to provide a bit more background information why and how your solutions answers this question.